# How to use p4 typemap programmatically (java) rather than using terminal?

Tags: java, perforce, p4v

I have to submit an XML file in Perforce Server. The value of an XML tag can be formed in any language like English, Japanese, Chinese etc. But when I add Japanese or Chinese language then the file type becomes binary instead of text. That's because the Perforce Server identifies binary and text files based on whether it detects non-text characters in the first 8192 bytes of the file.

After studying, I knew that there is a term called **p4 typemap** which can be used to override the default logic of auto detection of file type.

Reference: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3454

But the problem is that this solution is from p4v and terminal based but i want to know is there any way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a typemap to do this; you can also specify a filetype as a parameter to the `p4 add` command, e.g.:

```
p4 add -t binary blahblah.xml
```

If you have some XML files that are Unicode/binary and some that are ASCII, it makes more sense to specify this on a per-file basis rather than trying to capture it in a typemap.  The typemap is meant to be set up ahead of time by the admin to represent common overrides, not modified on the fly by applications.

To convert p4 commands/options into Java code, see the P4 Java API doc:

- https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4java-javadoc/
- https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/option/client/AddFilesOptions.html

Comment: AddFilesOptions addOptions = new AddFilesOptions();
  if (fileType != null) {
    addOptions.setFileType(fileType.toString());
  }

Comment: Can I set file type by this way?

Comment: Yep!  You want the "binary" type, or maybe "unicode" if your server is Unicode-enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much.